# Floating ListBox Elements in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, listbox

Is there a way to mimic the CSS `float: left;` behavior for ListBox elements?

I have a situation where I need to display a dynamic number of buttons on a page and they all need to sit next to each other. Something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------- 
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 | Button 4 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Again, the number of available buttons will not be known until run-time, so I can't just set up a grid to do this for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the SelectedItem Property in the ListBox, I would suggest using an ItemsControl and overriding the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel with an Orientation="Horizontal" like CamronBute mentioned.

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a StackPanel. It should allow resizing and do what you need